# In Swagger how to change the Json key name to use snake case naming convention

Tags: scala, swagger, swagger-ui, spray-json

I am using swagger to write in code API's documentation.
I am using gettyimages spray-swagger coding in Scala. I am using the below case class

case class Favourite(id: Long,tagType: String,tagDisplayName: String) 
and when I specify

```
@ApiOperation(httpMethod = "POST", value = "Add a new user favourite")
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "body", required = true, dataType = "com.dg.xyg.Favourite", paramType = "body", value = "Add new Favourite")
```

While displaying it displays me the body in ty out option in the case which i use to specify my variable name in Favourite case class as swagger picks body parameters from 'dataType' field in the @ApiImplicitParam.
Snake case name convention is the most important property of 'Json key'. I tried to use @ApiModel and @ApiModelProperty to place over each valiable in my case class but it didn't work out as @ApiModel does not have a 'name' field.

In spray-json you can give the customerized name to the json key  so i want to display this as well in the request body section of swagger ui